# «Делает что может». Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении с фразой "... делает(,) что может"?

Answer (score 3):

**... делает, что может.**

"Что может" — это неполное придаточное предложение.

Вот что пишет Розенталь.
Неполные придаточные предложения, а также обороты, не имеющие характера фразеологических сочетаний, запятыми отделяются, например: ***работает везде, где приходится; понимать, что к чему; не могу понять, где болит*.**
[Пунктуация при оборотах, не являющихся придаточными предложениями](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm)

Я думаю, что запятая нужна, потому что "делает, что может" не является неразложимым сочетанием (как, например,  ***делай что хочешь, бери что нравится, есть что дают, будь что будет***).

**Каждый делает, что может** ([журнал "Новый мир". Письма Жорж-Санд](https://books.google.ee/books?id=6cDZDwD0oVUC&pg=RA2-PA226&lpg=RA2-PA226&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82&source=bl&ots=SfYtyC2628&sig=ACfU3U02VBMngwGYiLHG85EJvfOmgK8J0w&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAtvmWjOnjAhVrmYsKHdaWC48Q6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82&f=false)).

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо Розенталю, и вот что я там нашел: *Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний, например: сделать как следует (как полагается, как подобает), выполнить как должно (как надо, как нужно), хватать что подвернется, явиться как ни в чем не бывало, **говорить что в ум взбредёт**, добиваться во что бы то ни стало, спрятаться кто куда успел, не лезть куда не следует, ночевать где придется, делай что хочешь, бери что нравится, спасайся кто может, есть что дают...*
Сравните: делает что может (многое, всевозможное). Делает всё, что может.
Итого: "делает что может" не разделяется как цельное выражение. А ещё может быть смысловая пунктуация: "ты можешь думать что хочешь" (всё что угодно) и "ты можешь думать, что хочешь" - т. е. что хочешь.